Designing a Social Network: Component Distribution
I need to create a simple social network for a Next JS and React course with a Home Page to show feed posts, a Navbar for navigation, a profile and notifications...
Obviously I know that each component will become client or server depending on its needs, but just for clarity I was wondering if there is a standard, some kind of rule, that suggests you which components to create as Server and which ones as Client.
For interactivity, you would need to use a client component. I wonder if it is really necessary to move the use of the client into the more specific components. After all, there is a possibility that a different approach might be more beneficial. We cannot rule out that there is a viable alternative, even considering the potential implications on server-side rendering.


I was wondering if there is a standard, some kind of rule, that
suggests you which components to create as Server and which ones as
Client.

I don't mean this unkindly, but I feel the answer to this is "the architecture".  As to what the architecture is - well, "it depends" is unfortunately the driver behind all architectures.
Let me see if I can provide some more practical advice...
Some topics where Client / Server is relevant, which might drive you to go one way or the other:

Network connectivity - if connectivity is poor or not available (e.g. using an app in "flight mode") then making something client-based seems obvious.
Performance - this depends on a huge variety of variables, and performance is relevant in all sorts of ways (compute speeds, transaction speeds, network speeds, capacity & volumes, etc).  If you have any sort of functionality where performance is important then a diagnosis of what's relevant should help point you clearly in one direction or the other.
Security - doing stuff on the client its relatively much more exposed compared to server-based execution.
Variability - client environments can be hugely varied - different device types, with different specs & resources, different operating systems, versions, etc.  This can lead to complications for support, testing, and so on.
Control and Stability - typically you'll have more control over the server environment that the client environment.  This includes being able to manage dependencies.
Frequency of change - following in from the previous point, its easier to iterate frequently and quickly on the server as you only have one environment to update, and it's in an environment you control.

